# Render JSON errors from two different hashes

Tags: javascript, json

Initially I had 1 hash that would just return the error for a form. However now I have two hashes that can contain errors. Now I'd like to look through both of them and display it to the user. What I had before when I only had 1, that was working was this piece of code:

```
<script>
  $("#payment-form").on("ajax:error", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    App.OrderRequests.throwFormError();
    $('#payment-form').render_form_errors(data.responseJSON)
  });

  $.fn.render_form_errors = function(errors) {
    var form;
    form = this;
    this.clear_form_errors();
    return $.each(errors, function(field, messages) {
      return form.append('<span class="help-block">' + $.map(messages, function(m) {
        return m.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + m.slice(1);
      }).join('<br />') + '</span>');
    });
  };

  $.fn.clear_form_errors = function() {
    this.find('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    return this.find('span.help-block').remove();
  };
</script>
```

This is already pushing my expertise with javascript. Now the typical JSON response I'd return would be like this:

```
"{\"base\":[\"Your card's security code is incorrect.\"]}"
```

However now I want to return the JSON like this (because I'm saving to two different models on the same form):

```
"{\"address\":{},\"card\":{\"base\":[\"Your card's security code is incorrect.\"]}}"
```

So I'd like to essentially print what errors might be hiding inside both address or card. So I need to adjust the code to check those, however I'm not sure how to achieve that.